# How to pass data in array in axios reponse

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, axios

I'm having a return function from the controller like this.

```
return [$masterIds, $detailIds];
```

How do i get the value from axios response?

```
axios.get('/viewrequestsample').then((response) => {
            this.items = response.data;
          })
```

I'm new in laravel. sending 1 value is great. but how about multiple? I'm just curious. Sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ususally you want to send the response like:

```
class HomeController{

  public function someFunc(){
    ...
    ...
   return response()->json([
      'array1'=> [], 
      'array2'=>[],
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: .will i put this inside my controller. Then how should i fetch this in the axios inside?.  this.items0 =  respond[0];  this.items1 =  respond[1]; ..Hope u rply. thanks a lot

Comment: this goes on a controller method is the response to your ajax.

Comment: .sir i want to pass an object inside an array. is that possible?

Comment: you can pass whatever you want `->json()` will cast the response to json . please accept the answer @chimichi004